# How to compare date range of one row against consecutive row that are grouped by ID in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

Please find the sample data frame

[image]

Have tried using lag function using `dplyr`. But couldn't get the expected result.

Code : Have tried something like this

```
df %>% 
group_by(Group) %>%
mutate(Result = case_when(Product != lag(Product) & Enddate <= lead(Enddate) ~ "within date range")
```

Expected Result is given in the dataframe column Result.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show a small reproudcible example and expected output instead of images

Comment: Also the code using ``dplyr`` , the resultant output and the expected output